# Deploy React Native Web static files to Firebase Hosting doesn't work

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have a React Native app. It works locally when I just use "expo start" and it also works serving the files via "npx serve dist --single".

What I would like to do is build the app into a bunch of static files and host them on Firebase Hosting.
I followed the instructions followed in the docs [here](npx serve dist --single) but it doesn't work.
Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Looking a it deeper; the HTML files that is served, looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Amplify</title>
    <!-- The `react-native-web` recommended style reset: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/setup/#root-element -->
    <style id="expo-reset">
      /* These styles make the body full-height */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* These styles disable body scrolling if you are using <ScrollView> */
      body {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      /* These styles make the root element full-height */
      #root {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        flex: 1;
      }
    </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /></head>

  <body>
    <!-- Use static rendering with Expo Router to support running without JavaScript. -->
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <!-- The root element for your Expo app. -->
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/_expo/static/js/web/entry-97e54fcf1c076f1bb36595244f148655.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks fine but the JS script is being loaded and the browser for some reason thinks it's supposed to be HTML so it gives an error.

For deploying I use this in my package.json

```
    "predeploy": "expo export -p web",
    "deploy-hosting": "npm run predeploy && firebase deploy --only hosting"
```

I also have a fairly standard firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then finally, my app.json just has a few property I want a single page as output. I tried outputting it with "static" and "server" but that didn't work either unfortunately.

```
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "single",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
```

Anyone any ideas why the JS is getting interpreted as html and how I can fix it?